# Latex: Longtable always starts in a new page leaving the previous page nearly empty (IEEE format )

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

Im new to using LaTeX. I am writing a Longtable that spread across 2 pages. But LaTeX always adds starts the table in a new page and so I end up with a long break in the previous page. Same thing happens after the table. The text continues on the next page.

I am writting for IEEE format paper. So am using `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` enclosing the longtable code.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: these empty pages problems are always tricky for me. I'd start by adding \raggedbottom and see if that helps...

Comment: Does `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` required? I think no. These commands creates the new page. Please post a minimal working example (MWE) which shows the problem.

Comment: I also face the same problem. I use longtable and a two-column document class.
I have done a deep search over the web, and tried different methods as suggested on the web. No a method really works. I finally have to manually move the tex code for the tables around in the body text. This is not perfect but at least can reduce some empty spaces before the tables. I am wondering whether there is a correct method to solve this problem.

Comment: I had the same situation. The table starts near the *top* of the page, but it decides to start on the next page, leaving the current one almost blank. My workaround is back to using the old `tabular` (wrapped inside `table` and `[H]` of course).

Answer (score 3):

`longtable` itself doesn't force a page break unless the table is going to start very near the bottom of the page, howver both the `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` commands do force a page break, so if you place those before and after `longtable` you will get a forced break.