# longtable is pushed to the next page

Tags: tables, longtable, emptypage

I can't create a MWE with this issue. Seems it's because of my whole document, as it works normally when I copy the table to a new file. I use these 2 rules:

- For short (10 < rows) tables, I use normal `tabular` wrapped inside `table`, with `[H]` to keep it in place (I really don't know any other way; some suggest skipping `table` but then I have to use `\\` to add some space).
- For long tables, I use `longtable`.

I use `booktabs` on both.

This is the problematic `longtable`:

[image: longtable is on the next page]

This is the same table, but using `tabular` inside `table` *without* `[H]`. The table jumps to before/above the text `We have the following table`:

[image: the same table inside tabular inside table without [H]]

This is my current workaround, using `tabular` inside `table` *with* `[H]`. This is the intended output, though I have to use `tabular`, which is inconsistent with my above rule:

[image: the same table inside tabular inside table with [H]]

In all 3 cases above, there're 2 `underfull` warning on the `\documentclass` line.

In a comment to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125566/206774) about a seemingly similar problem, it is suggested that I use `\raggedbottom`, but the info about that command is sparse and I don't know where to start.

How can I fix this, and keep using `longtable` instead of the workaround?

Comment: I don't use `tabular`, and everything is ok.

Comment: Show the code not images. You cannot put a longtable inside a table it does not make sense as a float like table cannot contain page breaks

Comment: @daleif No I didn't. I only wrap `tabular` inside `table`, and I can't recreate a MWE.

Comment: That's why you should give more information about your code. Here we're just shooting in the dark

Comment: You can always create a MWE, although one showing the problem might be difficult..  I like to use `\rule(1pt}{25\baselineskip}` (for example) to start at a particular line.